# JQuery - Copy response from AJAX request to clipboard without the user having to press a button again

Tags: jquery, ajax, clipboard

I am trying to copy a part of a JSON AJAX response to the user's clipboard. The user submits a form by pressing a button and I want the response to be copied to their clipboard without them having to interact with the page again.

What I have so far:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                ajax: ajax
            },
            success: function(result) {
                var results = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));

                let url = results['result']['url']; // Just a normal URL
                $("#content").append('<input id="copyurl" type="hidden" value="' + url + '">');
                $("#content").append('<button id="copy" class="hidden" onclick="copy()" />');

                $("#copy").click();

                //showSuccessIcon('absolute-center', 'The link has been copied to your clipboard!');
            },
            fail: function() {
                showErrorIcon('absolute-center', 'Oops! Could not connect to server.');
                throw new Error('Failed to send POST request');
            }
        });
    } catch(err) {
        showErrorIcon('absolute-center', 'Oops! Something went wrong.');
        throw new Error('Failed to send POST request: ' + err);
    }
});
```

copy():

```
function copy() {
    var click = document.getElementById("copyurl");
    click.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

The code first creates an input element 'copyurl' from which to copy the URL. It then creates a hidden button that it clicks, which executes the function copy().

This code does not do anything. I don't get any errors in the console and my clipboard remains the same.

I've read that the browser will not execute execCommand() without user input, so I'm not sure if what I'm proposing is even possible. :(

Answer (score 0):

so easy 
replace

```
$("#copy").click();
```

with

```
$("#copy").trigger('click');
```

Comment: The result sadly remains the same :(

Comment: please wait ! i implement code in jsfiddle and say you  :)

Comment: That wont work:
> "Due to security restrictions imposed by browser vendors, user interaction is required in order copy/cut to work. Which means that the first argument in the constructor is required and must refer to a valid element in the page. **A simulated click event using JavaScript does not work as this would enable clipboard poisoning.**"